# How to add multiple backslashes to a string in java?

Tags: java

I would like to add 2 numbers of backslash to the prefix of a RegEx to overcome dangling metacharacter exception. I am using the following piece of code:

```
    if (pattern != null) {
                pattern = pattern.trim();
        if (pattern.length() > 0) {
            if (pattern.indexOf("+[") >= 0) {
                pattern = "\\\\" + pattern;
}
                String formatterPattern ="formatter.setPattern(Pattern.compile(\"" + pattern + "\"));";

                System.out.println("formatterPattern : " + formatterPattern);
            }
}
```

But, I am getting,

```
formatter.setPattern(Pattern.compile("\+[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9()+-]{1,30}"));
```

instead of

`formatter.setPattern(Pattern.compile("\\+[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9()+-]{1,30}"));`

Even I tried with multiple `\\s` like, still, it adds only one backslash to the RegEx.

Comment: Try eight of those backslashes? Maybe they are being "double escaped" twice - once in a java string, once in the regex?

Comment: Seven backslashes isn't going to work. The compiler needs them in twos, and so does the regular-expression parser, so the only thing that's going to work is multiples of four. Unclear why you think you need to do this. The real problem with your regular expression is the missing leading `[`.

Comment: @vikingsteve : You are right! Tried with eight backslashes, Now, prefixes with 2 backslashes in the RegEx!

Comment: Okay, I switched my comment to answer if you'd like to accept i there.

Comment: I've tried out your piece of code and got two backslashes in the output, not one. There is no regex compilation here, so only Java replaces "\\" with one "\".